# Alert for event returning 'Undefined'

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, alert

***Parent Component :-***

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
    <aura:handler name="beerSearchEvent" event="c:SearchEvent" action="{!c.handleBeerSearchEvent}"/>
    <div>
        <c:HeaderComponent tagLine="Beer Explorer" message="For all fun to be..."/>
    </div>
    <c:BeerSearch/>
</aura:component>
```

***Parent Component Controller :-***

```
({
    handleBeerSearchEvent : function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        var searchParam = event.getParam('searchText');
        alert(searchParam);
    }
})
```

***Child Component :-***

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="beerSearchEvent" type="c:SearchEvent"/>
    <aura:attribute name="issearching" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
        <lightning:input aura:id="beerSearchButton" 
                         name="Beer Search" 
                         label="Your favourite beer just a search away..."
                         placeholder="Search Your Favourite Beer Here..."
                         type="search"
                         variant="label-hidden"
                         onchange="{!c.doSearch}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

***Child Component Controller :-***

```
({
    doSearch: function(component,event,helper)
    {
        var componentEvent = component.getEvent('beerSearchEvent');
        var beerSearchInput = component.find('beerSearchButton').get('v.value');
        componentEvent.setParam({searchText : beerSearchInput});
        componentEvent.fire();       
    }    
});
```

***Event :-***

```
<aura:event type="component" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="searchText" type="string"/>
</aura:event>
```

When I am running this in an Application, the alert is returning me **Undefined** but as per the expectation it should alert whatever I am entering in the Lightning : input Search. What i am doing wrong???
Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SecureEvent#setParam` expects two parameters, a `string` and an `object`:

```
componentEvent.setParam('searchText', beerSearchInput);
```

If you want to use object notation, use the plural version, `SecureEvent#setParams`:

```
componentEvent.setParams({searchText: beerSearchInput});
```

Comment: This worked!!! thanks a lot...
Been learning lightning for a while and these are small things that I need to learn and remember...

Comment: @SFDCAlex I always use setParams myself, even if there's only one, that way I don't have to worry about the other syntax.